# sshfs-mounts mysteriously disappear at login time

Tags: systemd, sshfs

**Status:** I have created a systemd service which successfully calls a shell script which in turn successfully mounts a few ssh shares using SSH keys (passwordless access).

**Problem:** When I log in these mounts are gone.

**Details:** The shell script proves successful mounting by sending directory listings of the freshly mounted ressources to its own logfile.

**Question:** What makes the mounts created during boot-up disappear, as soon as a user logs in to the machine?

**Remark:** If someone likes to see the sources, no problem, just ask.

Important: The mounts which are set up by the script during the boot process are lost as soon as I log in as a user. The problem is not that I could not work with these mounts due to insufficient rights, for example, but they are simply not there. Launching mount on the commandline to see what's there does not list them.

Comment: Does the systemd service exit and remove the fuse mount?  What does the systemctl status of the service say?

Comment: Yes, the service runs errorfree, and when systemd recognizes its correct exit status, it removes the mounts. Thus they're not available for the user anymore. This can be prevented by `RemainAfterExit=yes`.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was thinking was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Mounts aren't persistent through reboots. If you would like your mounts to remain, you have to add an entry to `/etc/fstab` (which is sourced before every boot).
Your entry should look something like this (replacing PATHs, HOST, etc):

```
sshfs#USER@HOST:REMOTE_PATH LOCAL_PATH fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

Comment: Excuse me, please, but I did not mention /etc/fstab at allow. The reason is that I did not use it for my solution. The script does all the mounting by command lines itself. I'll add a further comment with the script. Moreover, I was not talking about persistency between boots, then I did not need a service plus script at all. I was talking about a mount during boot up which should still be present when the first user logs in.

Comment: The shell script uses lines like this to mount: `/usr/bin/sshfs -o sshfs_debug,allow_other,default_permissions user@192.168.2.77:/Data /mnt/data`

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question for clarity in that case. Perhaps your mount is being overwritten somehow or permissions on the mount point are misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `RemainAfterExit=yes` in the `Service` section.